# Android soft keyboard - Need Android soft keyboard source code AOSP

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-source

Can anybody give me the source code of android soft keyboard AOSP?
I'm looking for a while but not found :(

There are so much things in default android keyboard I cannot found in others sample codes.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get source of every Android keyboard here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/

Edit: If you need directly "SoftKeyboard" go here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SoftKeyboard/

Source: google.com, you should google it yourself next time.

Comment: In actuality only part of the code is published.  The swipe functionality is not.